# Image size and dimensions reduce when I capture from camera

Tags: android

Using this to open camera:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

and in `OnActivityResult`:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (data != null) {
             if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
            {
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
            }
        }



private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {

        if (data != null) {    
            cameraBitMap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            cameraBitMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, bytes);
             cameraFilePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            FileOutputStream fo;
            try {
                cameraFilePath.createNewFile();
                fo = new FileOutputStream(cameraFilePath);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cameraFilePath.getAbsolutePath(), options);

            imageHeight = options.outHeight;
            imageWidth = options.outWidth;

            camImagePath = String.valueOf(cameraFilePath);
            String fileName = camImagePath.substring(camImagePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

            txt_FileName.setText(fileName);
            txt_FileName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btn_ImageTest.setImageBitmap(cameraBitMap);
        }

    }
```

[image]

I want the original size image to display when I capture it from the camera.

Comment: extras "data" is only thumbnail ... feel free to use search(I know it's very hard to do this before asking the question) to find out answer in many many similar questions

Comment: @Selvin..thank you now i know why size is so small because it is thumbnail..so can u guide me how to get image that i capture ?

Comment: 1. in web browser type google.com ... 2. then type your problem ... 3. follow the links

Comment: Think that OP will only start searching knowing the answer. Much easier! ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent like this. Here first give image name .

```
//declare globally
private static final int CAMERA_CODE = 101 ;
private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
```

Start Intent as below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp1.jpg");
if (f.exists()) {
      f.delete();
}
mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CODE);
```

And in `onActivityResult` :

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        System.out.println("Camera Image URI : " + mImageCaptureUri);

        String path = mImageCaptureUri.getPath();
        if (new File(path).exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Path is Exists..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        btn_ImageTest.setImageURI(mImageCaptureUri);
    }
}
```

Comment: i got your point but not going into if (requestCode == CAMERA_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {}

if i comment this portion :
File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp1.jpg");
if (f.exists()) {
      f.delete();
}
mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);

then it goes into :
if (requestCode == CAMERA_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
}

Comment: post your if condition in `onActivityResult`

Comment: same as u wrote just made one change:
i put your  if (requestCode == CAMERA_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){} under one condition: if(data!=null)

Comment: Ok, got your problem.when we declare predefined path for image , then data is null . so first condition is getting always false.

Comment: so remove `if(data!=null){}` condition.

Comment: i removed that condition now getting image but same as before small size like thumbnail

Comment: which device you use?

Comment: currently testing in emulator with NExus 5..let me check in real device

Answer (score 0):

You need to create temporary file before you start Camera Activity Intent.

Anything that using below code or similar like that after you take image using camera actually is a thumbnail image which is reduced the original quality.

This is the code that I meant:

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```

[Refer Here for more info](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPhotoView)

**This are the solution that you want**

1. First You need to create temporary file.
2. Convert the temporary file into URI
3. Pass URI data to Camera intent by using putExtra method.
4. Open Camera Activity intent.
5. Handle onActivityResult if user cancel or accept the image from Camera Activity intent.

Below are the method you can use for step by step mentioned above.

**Create Temporary File.**

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
// Create an image file name
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File image = File.createTempFile(
    imageFileName,  /* prefix */
    ".jpg",         /* suffix */
    storageDir      /* directory */
);

// Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
return image;
}
```

**Convert Temporary file to URI and invoke camera activity intent.**

```
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
Uri photoURI;
File photoFile;
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
// Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    // Create the File where the photo should go
    photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Error occurred while creating the File
        ...
    }
    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
    if (photoFile != null) {
        photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                              "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                                              photoFile);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
    }
}
}
```

Now you already have File location path created before Camera Activity intent called. You can handle RESULT_OK(Show image) or RESULT_CANCELED(Delete temporary image).

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {            
        mImageView.setImageURI(photoURI );
    }else{
       photoFile.delete();
    }
}
```

*Take note on getUriForFile which returns a content:// URI. For more recent apps targeting Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher, passing a file:// URI across a package boundary causes a FileUriExposedException. Therefore, we now present a more generic way of storing images using a FileProvider.
Full documentation is here for reference.

[Taking Photo Simply](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath)